# Nunjucks - force the display of added values to display with 2 decimal points (currency)

Tags: nunjucks

I’m using this nunjucks code to add 2 currency values together:

`{{(data['facility-1new-paid'] | float) + (data['facility-5new-paid'] | float) }}`

I want it to force display the result with 2 decimal points whatever the value. Eg 10.00 or 10.20 or 10.26

But it displays the above examples as 10 or 10.2 or 10.26

Any help to force the 2 decimal points would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`float`-filter just converts any to float and it works.
But then you need to format the output. Use `toFixed` js-method for it.

```
{{ (val).toFixed(2) }} 
...

{{((data['facility-1new-paid'] | float) + (data['facility-5new-paid'] | float)).toFixed(2) }}
```